# Excel (xls) preprocessor for karma

Tags: angularjs, excel

I've come across a block of code in our Angular application that makes use  of `xls.js` to open and process Excel files in Javascript. The problem is how I can go about testing these functions?

I'm trying to go down the route of preprocessors inside the `karma.conf.js` file and ahve installed the node module for excel parsing like so:

```
npm install excel-parser
```

which successfully installed the module to my `node_modules` folder. My preprocessor command in karma currently looks like this:

```
 preprocessors: {
      'src/main/webapp/partials/common/components/header-bar/header-bar.html': ['ng-html2js'],
      'src/main/webapp/partials/visibility/visibility/import/test/test_spreadsheet.xls': ['excelParser.js']
 },
```

and I've added the target excel file to the list of files using the same path above. Karma fires an error on start up:

```
WARN [preprocessor]: Can not load "excelParser.js"
Error: No provider for "preprocessor:excelParser"! (Resolving: preprocessor:excelParser)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

thrown on the spreadsheet's first line.

Anyone else handle Excel procesing with Karma or can suggest an alternative to the route I'm going down?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Karma doesn't run files, it runs whole modules as preprocessors, you need to write a preprocessor plugin wrapper for excelParser: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/dev/plugins.html

Comment: @TheZ yeah I thought that that may be the only option though we're approaching the end of the test phase and may not have time to investigate and create it. I was hoping one would have already have been created...